# WiX Visual Studio Setup Project: How to build different msi in one project, depending on preprocessor variables

Tags: wix, setup-project

Such a situation: i have one wxs build file. it is based on 3 preprocessor variables:

```
Build=[Client\Server] 
Platform=[Win32\x64]
Configuration=[Release\Debug]
```

Only thing i need is to create a setup visual studio project, that can build all this 8 configurations of my install package at once.

E.g.

```
Cmd.exe «candle.exe –dPlatform=Win32 –dConfiguration=Debug –dBuild=Server Product.wxs»
Cmd.exe «light.exe –ext WixUIExtension –ext WiXIISExtension Product.wixobj –out Product_Server(Release)_x86.msi»
```

and

```
Cmd.exe «candle.exe –dPlatform=Win32 –dConfiguration=Release –dBuild=Server Product.wxs»
Cmd.exe «light.exe –ext WixUIExtension –ext WiXIISExtension hsm.wixobj –out Product_Server(Release)_x86.msi»
```

But i cannot use command-prompt based solution. Need an exectly WiX setup solution.

Is there some advises?

Comment: The only way i found, is to create 2 different solutions based on one source wxs file, use WPlatform and WConfiguration and use different values of Build in different solutions. Is there a way to have just 1 solution?

Comment: Agrh! This issue cannot create msi with different names in one solution. Guys!!! Any sujestions plz!

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be an unresolvable issue. The only way - to create different projects... From the vs we can operate only such preprocessor variables as 'Platform' and 'Configuration'. Every additional preprocessor variable force us to multiple our solutions in "variable_range".

The obvious advice is to separate ur source codes in different files. Just to consentrate ur attention to the proper way of development each build. But this way brings more readability to the source code.

May be deleted... but, if somebody knows the real resolution of this issue... plz let me know.

Comment: this question is like a diary of developer... just ur thoughts... Does Nobody really can answer.. even "There is no way of resolving"...

Answer (score 1):

You can create separate outputs by creating new build configurations. For example, we have two products built from very similar sources. You can specify the output name in the propertygroup. It'll take hand editing of your wixproj, but will load up just fine in visual studio.

Do something like this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug (App1)' ">
    <OutputName>App1</OutputName>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug (App2)' ">
    <OutputName>App2</OutputName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Visual studio should show two configurations - Debug (App1) and Debug (App2).

Answer (score 0):

I have spent the last 1/2 day trying to resolve this.  It looks to me like the only approach is separate projects.  I *was* trying a command line recompile of the project, but it appears that MSBuild is not detecting a change in a build property when compiling wixproj files and then the WiX compiler isn't picking up the right source files after I run a 'clean' to force the recompile.

At least with multiple projects the source code can be shared and all used in a single solution.